# Is there any reason to use an upright microscope over an inverted microscope?

Tags: lab-techniques, microscopy

I've never actually owned an inverted microscope, but it seems it has only advantages compared to an upright microscope: taller, heavier samples; no crashing the objective into the glass slide; easier to operate, etc.

Why then do people still use regular, upright microscopes? Is there a disadvantage I'm missing?

Comment: Cost?  A quick search shows inverted microscopes costing several thousand dollars, while a decent upright can be had for a few hundred.

Comment: @jamesqf Yup, seems obvious now... Should I delete the question?

Comment: There might be other reasons - I'm certainly not an expert!

Comment: For metallurgical microscopes there is little difference. I would say individuals chose on the basis of  quality ( image ,light, and mechanical). We nominally had about a dozen , mostly different , from Leitz to Unitron. Some console types like Richert (?) were only used for special jobs as they tended to be less convenient My boss loved old B & L where you physically removed the objectives - no turret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, cost is one of the primary reasons when you're looking at simple light microscopes. Inverted scopes have more complex optics, along with the convenience factor of being able to examine larger samples, generally having a more stable frame, etc. All this leads to higher cost.

An advantage I can think of for smaller upright scopes is the ability to use them as a dissecting scope, where the sample is opaque and you need to see it from above. Another advantage is this:

[image: fluorescence microscope]

Many fluorescence microscopes are upright, as there is a significant amount of extra equipment that needs to be mounted in addition to the eyepiece, including lasers, stage motors, and cameras and other detectors. This can take up a *lot* of room, and for convenience's sake it's often easiest to mount it up top where it is accessible.

Comment: Doesn't the extra equipment usually have to be built in, though, or at least have ports & fittings on the microscope to allow it to be added?  Which would raise the cost.

Comment: @jamesqf correct, which is why I clarified that the cost argument really only applies for simple "magnification-only" light microscopes. Once you start getting into very high magnification, fluorescence, live sample chambers, etc., cost starts to skyrocket.

Answer (score 2):

Because inverted microscopes use a long working distance condenser (which allows them to fit plates, flasks, roller bottles, etc) - the resolution in transmitted light is inherently limited.  An upright microscope with a standard condenser will deliver much better results at higher magnification when you are imaging slides.

Consider your resolution in transmitted light a function of objective resolution AND condenser resolution.  If you have a high resolution objective but a low resolution condenser then you are inherently limited by the condenser regardless of how good of an objective lens you have.

A typical condenser on an upright microscope has a working distance of 1mm and a numerical aperture of 0.9/1.25.  So the condenser is right on top of your sample delivering the light needed by higher resolution objectives to perform.  A typical condenser on an inverted microscope has a working distance of 72mm and numerical aperture of 0.30 (of course there are alternate choices, this is just the most common).  So on the inverted the microscope the condenser that delivers light into your objective lens is 72mm away and has limited NA/resolving power.  This is just fine for the lower mag and long working distance objectives used for tissue culture because the LD objectives already have limited numerical aperture/resolving power.  But if you were imaging slides with standard working distance objectives which have higher apertures (especially if you are using oil immersion objectives i.e. 100x or 63x) - the condenser on an inverted microscope doesn't cut it and you need an upright microscope.

Comment: This looks like a great informative answer, but it would be helped by citing sources.